# Is there a way that a div with a background-image and float property will not be overlapped?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a div that must be floated to the right and have a background image. I put that div inside of another one for display purposes. I am having problems with not letting the text after the inner div overlap the pictureDiv.

I cannot place this in a table because then the text would not be able to bend around the image if need be. While I am here, is there a way to make text that I place after my outerDiv start after the outerDiv? My problems would both be solved if I was told a way to make these divs unoverlappable.

```
<div id="outerDiv">
<div id="pictureDiv" style="background-image: url(http://thomasmorestudies.org/gallery_art/g-a5_l.jpg); 

background-repeat: no-repeat; float: right;">

<center>[<a onclick="Hide()" href="javascript:void(0);">Click here for full photo</a>]</center>
<hr>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You want the two divs to not overlap eachother, meaning you want them to be one on top of the other?

Comment: Can you please provide a JS fiddle?

Comment: You may need to clear your float.  To achieve this in modern browsers (IE8+) simply set a block formatting context for outerDiv.  An easy way to do this is by setting it's overflow to hidden.  If you need to support older browsers I would suggest searching and reading about clearfix.

Comment: @ user1152309: Yes, I want one on top of the other, but not over the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following might be close to what you are trying to do:

The HTML:

```
<div class="outerDiv">
    <div class="pictureDiv"></div>
    <div class="caption">[<a href="$">Click here for full photo</a>]</div>
    <hr>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
.outerDiv {
    border: 1px solid blue;
    overflow: auto;
    /* this clears the floated content */
}
.pictureDiv {
    background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/300/300);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    float: right;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    margin-bottom: 1.00em;
}
.caption {
    text-align: center;
    clear: both;
}
```

See demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/8ZHqE/

I was not sure where you wanted the caption, so I put it outside of the `.pictureDiv`, but I can alter it.  Please comment!

Comment: I was trying to do something like this: [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8ZHqE/1/).  
I also found the problem, I contained the comment div in the same div as the background picture div, so of course it would overlap. X)
Thank you for your demo, you were pretty much spot on.

Answer (score 0):

A floating div would float inside its container. Therefore, the background image of the outer div would always be underneath the inside floating div.

I see one best solution for this.
That would be to use a third div for the background:

HTML:

```
<div class="outer">
<div class="left-with-background">
</div>
<div class="right-floating">
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.outer { overflow: hidden; }
.left-with-background { background-image: url(images/back.png); }
.right-floating { float: right }
```

Answer (score 0):

1) You can use a padding-top: value of the same height of the image for the div "picture" 
2) You can put the href out of the div

Hint: change the `<center>` tag

```
<div id="outerDiv">
<div id="pictureDiv" style="background-image: url(http://thomasmorestudies.org/gallery_art/g-a5_l.jpg); 

background-repeat: no-repeat; float: right; padding-top:400px">
<span style="">[<a onclick="Hide()" href="javascript:void(0);">Click here for full photo</a>]</span>
<hr>
</div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tQ477/

Comment: The answer was the second option. I didn't realize I put the link in the same div as the background image div.  So, <div id="outerDiv"><div id="pictureDiv"></div> link here </div>, is what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Using float on first element and "has layout" on second should fix your problem, **no matter sizes of screen or floatting element**:
http://jsfiddle.net/3yAJx/

```
#pictureDiv {
    background-image: url(http://thomasmorestudies.org/gallery_art/g-a5_l.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    float: right;
}
#text {
    overflow:hidden;
    /* old IE */
    zoom:1;
}
```